# MKMapView: Use of Undeclared Identifier 'ann'?

Tags: objective-c, json, mkmapview, identifier

So I'm pulling together my mapview with coordinates from a MySQL database. I think I'm nearly there, but for some reason xcode keeps throwing me the "Use of Undeclared Identifier 'ann'". What on earth am I doing wrong? Here's my code...

**MapViewAnnotation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MKAnnotation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;


}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;



@end
```

**MapViewAnnotation.M**

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize title, coordinate, subtitle;

-(void)dealloc{
    [title release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface MapViewController : UIViewController  <MKMapViewDelegate> 

    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *Dispensaries;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *data;



@end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"


@implementation MapViewController
@synthesize mapView;
@synthesize Dispensaries;
@synthesize data;



- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidUnload];




        NSLog(@"Getting Device Locations");

        NSString *hostStr = @"http://stylerepublicmagazine.com/dispensaries.php";
        NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
        NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        id object = [serverOutput JSONValue];
        NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)object;

        for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {

            CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {[[dictionary objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[dictionary objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]};

            Annotation *ann = [[Annotation alloc] init];
            ann.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
            ann.coordinate = coord;
            [mapView addAnnotation:point];




    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];



    self.mapView.delegate = self;


}

}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation

{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];


MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
point.title = @"You Are Here";
point.subtitle = @"Your current location";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];



}
```

Comment: What is Annotation? You have a class implementing the MKAnnotation protocol, that's what you should be instantiating? Also, variable names should not be capitalized (Dispensaries).

Comment: Omg, how did I miss that (I've been staring at this computer for far too long). Thank you!!

Comment: haha nbd… :) you are close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to fix, simply change the type Annotation to MapViewAnnotation, and make the name of the array dispensaries.

Comment: Totally fixed. But now (this program is the devil), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543777/instance-method-jsonvalue-not-found-return-type-defaults-to-id

Comment: Can you check my answer? (looking at next thing… :) )

Comment: Which answer? And changed array name to 'dispensaries'.

Comment: @user1953744 this one we are commenting on. Click the checkbox. :) That's how this site works. Thanks!

Comment: Oooh LOL. Sorry. Checked :)