# Calling coordinates from MySQL database with this code causes simulator to display a SIGABRT error. What's wrong?

Tags: mysql, json, crash, mkmapview, sigabrt

When I use this code to try and call Lat & Long coordinates from a MySQL database (and display them on a MapView), the app runs fine. Everything appears to work, but for some reason, xcode pauses the simulator before the map loads, and throws me a SIGABRT. Any idea why? See below:

**MapViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


    @interface MapViewController : UIViewController  <MKMapViewDelegate> 

        @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
        @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *dispensaries;
        @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableData *data;


    @end
```

**MapViewController.m**

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"


    @implementation MapViewController
    @synthesize mapView;
    @synthesize dispensaries;
    @synthesize data;



    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
        self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
        if (self) {
            // Custom initialization
        }
        return self;
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

    - (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidUnload];



            NSLog(@"Getting Device Locations");

            NSString *hostStr = @"http://stylerepublicmagazine.com/dispensaries.php";
            NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostStr]];
            NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"server output: %@", serverOutput);
            NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)dispensaries;
            dispensaries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

            for (NSDictionary *dictionary in array) {



                CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {[[dictionary objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[dictionary objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]};

                MapViewAnnotation *ann = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] init];
                ann.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
                ann.coordinate = coord;
                [mapView addAnnotation:ann];



        [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
        [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
        [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];



        self.mapView.delegate = self;


    }

    }

    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation

    {
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
        [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];


    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"You Are Here";
    point.subtitle = @"Your current location";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];



    }
```

Comment: There's not enough information here. You are sending JSONValue to an NSString. Unless you added a Category that would provide that method, you are not going to get anything back from that. You should be seeing a warning in Xcode that there is no method in that class?

Comment: Odd... Nope. Don't get that error at all. Okay. So wait, my goal with this code is to: Have my MapView pull coordinates from the MySQL database (fields called lat & lng) via the stated PHP file (dispensaries.php), and display them as annotations on the map. I feel like I'm missing something totally elementary. Ha ha!

Comment: If that thing is returning JSON, then you are going to have to parse it, NSString is not going to just turn it into an id. Put this in right before the id object line: NSLog(@"server output: %@", serverOutput); then post the results here.

Comment: 2013-01-26 20:53:45.301 Cannabis MX iPhone App[41576:207] Getting Device Locations
2013-01-26 20:53:46.111 Cannabis MX iPhone App[41576:207] server output:   [{"DispensaryId":"1","Name":"Alan's Dispensary","Address1":"#2005-1028 Barclay Street","lat":"49.280096","lng":"-123.131461"},{"DispensaryId":"2","Name":"Blair's Dispensary","Address1":"1055 Homer Street","lat":"11.393879","lng":"-10.942383"}]
2013-01-26 20:53:46.112 Cannabis MX iPhone App[41576:207] -[__NSCFString JSONValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x79335e0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so now you have the JSON. You are going to have to decode that using [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Or, if you want to turn that into objects, you could use my open source library on GitHub, which allows you to simply implement NSCoding protocol and instantiate objects (or encode them) as JSON. That's [here](http://github.com/ontometrics/JSONCoding.git).

Comment: Side note: I'm pulling JSON from the MySQL database through one of my other controllers into a tableview (it works great). RE: Parsing JSON in this case, shouldn't I just be able to use:  dispensaries = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];

Comment: Where are you doing that here? Maybe you cut and pasted this in and left that code behind??

Comment: Um, my answer was the right one? I think the right thing would have been to check mine and update the question. Now you've made this into another question, from inside an Answer?

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, my fault! Let's try this again, Lol (this site is new to me). Just updated my original question =)

Comment: But you didn't check my answer. :O